# Egress Rule|| allow traffic to all cidr that start with 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, yaml, aws-cloudformation, ip-address

I'm trying to create egress rule via CFT to allow all ports to ip destination that starts with 10 in this way: `10.*.*.*/*`

```
  Egress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
    Properties:
      GroupId: 'sg-xxx'
      IpProtocol: -1
      FromPort: -1
      ToPort: -1
      CidrIp: 10.*.*.*/*
      Description: Custom egress with destination starts with 10
```

Running the above lead to this error: CIDR block is malformed Error Code: InvalidParameterValue

How can i pass this value in the correct format?

Comment: You would want to use `10.0.0.0/8` instead. CIDR blocks are not regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CIDR of `/8`:

```
  Egress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
    Properties:
      GroupId: 'sg-xxx'
      IpProtocol: -1
      FromPort: -1
      ToPort: -1
      CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/8
      Description: Custom egress with destination starts with 10
```